# PLSQL: Parsing and inserting data from XML to tables

Tags: xml, parsing, plsql, procedure

I have the following tables:

```
 create table TBL$ORDERS  
(  
  order_num  VARCHAR2(25),  
  employee   VARCHAR2(100),  
  createddt  VARCHAR2(20),  
  modifieddt VARCHAR2(20),  
  deleteddt  VARCHAR2(20),  
  state      VARCHAR2(15),  
  ts         VARCHAR2(20),  
  nni        VARCHAR2(20),  
  constraint pk_orders primary key (order_num)  
);  

create table TBL$METERS  
(  
  order_num  VARCHAR2(25),  
  xmlid      VARCHAR2(5),  
  createddt  VARCHAR2(20),  
  modifieddt VARCHAR2(20),  
  deleteddt  VARCHAR2(20),  
  vendor     VARCHAR2(25),  
  model      VARCHAR2(25),  
  serial     VARCHAR2(25),  
  constraint pk_meters primary key (order_num, xmlid),  
  constraint fk_orders foreign key (order_num) references TBL$ORDERS (order_num)  
);  

create table TBL$TESTS  
(  
  order_num    VARCHAR2(25),  
  meterxmlid   VARCHAR2(5),    
  xmlid        VARCHAR2(5),    
  createddt    VARCHAR2(20),  
  testcount    VARCHAR2(5),  
  successcount VARCHAR2(5),  
  test1        VARCHAR2(50),  
  test2        VARCHAR2(50),  
  test3        VARCHAR2(50),  
  test4        VARCHAR2(50),  
  constraint pk_tests primary key (order_num, meterxmlid, xmlid),  
  constraint fk_meters foreign key (order_num, meterxmlid) references TBL$METERS (order_num, xmlid)  
);
```

Which I want to populate with this code:

```
procedure PopulateTables(pXMLClob clob) is  
begin  
  for recOrders in (  
    select *  
    from   XMLTable(  
             '/Orders/Order'  
             passing XMLType(pXMLClob)  
               columns  
                 order_num  VARCHAR2(25)  path '@order_num',  
                 employee   VARCHAR2(100) path '@employee',  
                 createddt  VARCHAR2(20)  path '@createdDT',  
                 modifieddt VARCHAR2(20)  path '@modifiedDT',  
                 deleteddt  VARCHAR2(20)  path '@deletedDT',  
                 state      VARCHAR2(15)  path '@state',  
                 ts         VARCHAR2(20)  path '@ts',  
                 nni        VARCHAR2(20)  path '@nni',  
                 Meters     xmltype      path 'Meter'  
             )  
  )  
  loop  
    insert into TBL$ORDERS(order_num, employee, createddt, modifieddt, deleteddt, state, ts, nni)  
    values (recOrders.order_num, recOrders.employee, recOrders.createddt, recOrders.modifieddt, recOrders.deleteddt, recOrders.state, recOrders.ts, recOrders.nni);  
    for recMeters in (  
      select *  
      from   XMLTable(  
               '/Orders/Order'  
               passing XMLType(recOrders.Meters)  

                 columns  
                    xmlid      VARCHAR2(5)  path '@xmlid',  
                    createddt  VARCHAR2(20) path '@createdDT',  
                    modifieddt VARCHAR2(20) path '@modifiedDT',  
                    deleteddt  VARCHAR2(20) path '@deletedDT',  
                    vendor     VARCHAR2(25) path '@vendor',  
                    model      VARCHAR2(25) path '@model',  
                    serial     VARCHAR2(25) path '@serial',  
                    order_num  VARCHAR2(25) path '@order_num',  
                    tests      xmltype      path 'test'  
             )      
    )  
    loop  
      insert into TBL$METERS (order_num, xmlid, createddt, modifieddt, deleteddt, vendor, model, serial)  
      values (recOrders.order_num, recMeters.xmlid, recMeters.createddt, recMeters.modifieddt, recMeters.deleteddt, recMeters.vendor, recMeters.model, recMeters.serial);  
      for recTest in (  
        select *  
        from   XMLTable(  
                 '/Orders/Order'  
                 passing XMLType(recMeters.Tests)  
                 columns 
  xmlid        VARCHAR2(5) path '@xmlID',
  createddt    VARCHAR2(20) path '@createdDT',
  testcount    VARCHAR2(5) path '@testCount',
  successcount VARCHAR2(5) path '@successCount',
  test1        VARCHAR2(50) path '@test1',
  test2        VARCHAR2(50) path '@test2',
  test3        VARCHAR2(50) path '@test3',
  test4        VARCHAR2(50) path '@test4',
  meter_xmlid  VARCHAR2(5) path '@xmlID',
  order_order_num varchar(25) path '@order_num' 

               )          
      )  
      loop  

      insert into TBL$TESTS (xmlid, createddt, testcount, successcount, test1, test2, test3, test4, meter_xmlid , order_order_num  )  
      values (recTest.xmlid, recTest.createddt, recTest.testcount, recTest.successcount, recTest.test1, recTest.test2, recTest.test3, recTest.test4, recMeters.xmlid, recOrders.Order_num);

      end loop;    
    end loop;   
  end loop;  
  commit;    
end;
```

I get an error at lines passing XMLTYPE().

> ora-00306 wrong number of types or arguments in call to XMLTYPE.

Could someone show me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide your code directly to Stack Overflow

Comment: Please add the entire error message, including the line number.  And it will also help to reduce the code as much as possible.  The larger the code, the less likely someone is to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I did formulate an Answer to your previous Question, which you have deleted.  I have changed it to suit the new Question.  The issues are the same.</sub>

---

### Approach

> Make relations between these tables
>   I need to make relations between these tables using PKs and FKs.

It doesn't work like that.  I appreciate that you have a task, and a narrow focus to just get the job done, but that mindset is fraught with problems.  Not only right now, but predictable and preventable errors that will be exposed in the future.

The correct approach is to:

- create a database that matches (is a map of) the natural universe.  Why ?  Because the structure of the universe does not change (the content does).

  - This will make your app immune to change (from the changes coming in from the XML side).
  - Otherwise, each time the XML (a) changes or (b) you find an error (there are some right now!) and need to fix it, you have to change the structure of the database.  And therefore the code.

The opposite is to maintain a developer's view of the data (what you need right now) which has little to do with the real world.  Wherein you never actually understand the data as it is, and you will be working with data as fragments, and you will keep moving them around like a shell game.

> I have the following tables:

There is the first misunderstanding.  Those are not tables, that is simply the definition of the incoming XML.  To think of them as tables means you think that that is the final product that you need to implement in the database.  And then the perception of the real world, and how the data represents it, is lost.

- the truth is, you have an XML file definition, which is not 1::1 a table, which is not 1::1 the real world

> I was told that one Order can have many Meters, and one Meter can have many Tests.
>   But, I don't see attributes in these tables that can make a relation

That is because there aren't any (in the XML).  Again, you have to figure it out, again, the best bet is the real world, not the XML.

> there should be field order_num in meter table, and meter_id in Test table.

That is ok if you want a 1960's Record Filing System, which is what the "theoreticians" and the authors that follow them falsely promote as "relational".  Highly limited, and no integrity.

I see that you have now added those fields.

Here is a good example of how it does not have any integrity.

- **How is a Meter identified [correctly] ?**

  - you will say `primary key ( order_num, xmlid )`,
  - but that is wrong, `xmlid` is merely the line no that the XML developer assigned to the lines under `Orders`
  - if you use it, you will be logging Readings from Meter X against Meter X one day, and logging Readings from Meter X against Meter Y the next day.  And vice versa.
  - even they know that there is a problem, that the Meters in the field [for any given Order] keep changing (note `modifieddt` and `deleteddt`)
  - they have given you `( vendor, model, serial )`
  - that is the only valid PK for Meter (if you wish to prevent preventable errors)
  - `xmlid` is totally irrelevant to you (it is relevant only to the XML developer), it can be excluded from the XML file

### Relational Database

I can provide the Relational database that you need for this task.  It has complete data integrity.  But this is a first cut, not complete.  Why ?  Because there are severe errors in the XML file.  Once you get those errors fixed, I can tweak the database, and it will be complete.

[image: DM]

- "Test" might not be a good label.  When the test phase is complete, it will be a **Reading** of the **Meter**
- There appears to be four **Samples** in a Reading
- Employee may not be that important, I have given it in order to be complete
- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading.

#### Errors is XML File

(Referring to the XML file given in the deleted Question.

- Must not allow `serial` to be Null
- `Test` (even better `test1..4`) must identify the applicable Meter by (Vendor, Model, SerialNo)
- The 4 Samples in each `Test` are not Normalised, there should be 4 XML records (for each of `test1..4`)
- `test4` has a DateTime, but not `test1..3`
- DateTime in `test4` needs to be Format 23 (same as the other DateTimes)
- Does Employee identify the Order, or the MeterReading ?  I have modelled the former.

In the end, once the duplication and silliness is removed, the [XML file that is required for the purpose](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/user11913918%20DA.txt), is far more simple than they one they have given you.

---

### Parse XML

> But then, I have a problem with my parser xml procedure. Could you read my procedure and help me to include FK in it as well?

1. No.  That is outside the scope of this question.  Ask a new Question, and get someone in that domain to help you.
2. The link fails.
3. Frankly, I never bother with products that purport to parse XML, they are more trouble than they are worth, and when they fail, you have to fiddle with it yourself.  I just write code to parse XML, it is simple enough.  I use `awk` for all such jobs, all ETL.

   - `perl` is even better, because it has a PLSQL-Client connection to the database, but it requires some set up.  I think the Oracle variant is `oraperl`.

### PLSQL Proc

I do not have Oracle expertise, so I can't respond to that at the code level.  But let me say, if you understand my Answer here, and implement tables that match the real world, your code will be simple.

- the first thing to be understood here is, you cannot just import the XML file into the database (using either an XML parser or Oracle `LOOP`).  Why ? Because, again, the XML does not match the real world or the database (whereas the database does match the real world).
- what you need is normal SQL ACID Transactions (in Oracle, usually implemented as a proc).
- there is much **information** that comes in in the XML file, that has not been made explicit:

  - when a new Order or Meter comes in, you need to
    `IF NOT EXISTS ... INSERT` that first, before
    `INSERTing` the Readings and Samples
  - when the `modifieddt` or `deleteddt` in Order or Meter changes, you need to
    `UPDATE` those columns

Again, that is why I use `awk` to parse the XML file and produce a series of correct, applicable SQL commands.